# PyPyの再帰関数の仕様はPythonのものと異なるか

Tags: python, python3

### 実行環境

- Python 3.10.8
- PyPy 7.3.11 with MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)

### 質問

[AtCoder Beginner Contest 236 のD問題](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc236/tasks/abc236_d)に回答している際に，同じスクリプト・標準入力に対してPyPyとPythonで標準出力が異なるという現象に遭遇しました．

PyPyでは再帰が途中で終了しており，これはPythonのような意図する動作ではありません．

これは仕様ですか．またPyPyでPythonと同じような出力を得るために，何をすべきですか．

### 問題のスクリプト

```py
# script.py

import operator
import functools

# input -----

n = int(input())
a = [[0] * n * 2 for _ in range(n * 2)]

for i in range(2 * n - 1):
    for j, e in enumerate(map(int, input().split()), i + 1):
        a[i][j] = a[j][i] = e

# -----------


def rec(i):
    global ans

    if not __debug__:
        print(f"called rec({i = })\n  {pairs = }\n  {not_selected = }\n  {ans = }\n")

    if i == 2 * n:
        ans = max(
            ans,
            functools.reduce(
                operator.xor,
                (a[e1 - 1][e2 - 1] for e1, e2 in zip(*[iter(pairs)] * 2)),
                0,
            ),
        )
        return

    if i % 2 == 0:
        e = min(not_selected)
        pairs.append(e)
        not_selected.discard(e)
        rec(i + 1)
        pairs.pop()
        not_selected.add(e)
    else:
        for e in not_selected:
            pairs.append(e)
            not_selected.discard(e)
            rec(i + 1)
            pairs.pop()
            not_selected.add(e)


pairs = []
not_selected = set(range(2 * n))
ans = 0

rec(0)
print(ans)
```

### 標準入力

```
2
4 0 1
5 3
2
```

### Pythonでの実行結果

```
$ python -O script.py

 ~ console input ~

called rec(i = 0)
  pairs = []
  not_selected = {0, 1, 2, 3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 1)
  pairs = [0]
  not_selected = {1, 2, 3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 2)
  pairs = [0, 1]
  not_selected = {2, 3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 3)
  pairs = [0, 1, 2]
  not_selected = {3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 1, 2, 3]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 2)
  pairs = [0, 2]
  not_selected = {1, 3}
  ans = 4

called rec(i = 3)
  pairs = [0, 2, 1]
  not_selected = {3}
  ans = 4

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 2, 1, 3]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 4

called rec(i = 2)
  pairs = [0, 3]
  not_selected = {1, 2}
  ans = 4

called rec(i = 3)
  pairs = [0, 3, 1]
  not_selected = {2}
  ans = 4

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 3, 1, 2]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 4

called rec(i = 2)
  pairs = [0, 2]
  not_selected = {1, 3}
  ans = 6

called rec(i = 3)
  pairs = [0, 2, 1]
  not_selected = {3}
  ans = 6

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 2, 1, 3]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 6

called rec(i = 2)
  pairs = [0, 3]
  not_selected = {2, 1}
  ans = 6

called rec(i = 3)
  pairs = [0, 3, 1]
  not_selected = {2}
  ans = 6

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 3, 1, 2]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 6

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 3, 1, 2]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 6

6
```

### PyPyでの実行結果

```
$ pypy -O test.py

 ~ console input ~

called rec(i = 0)
  pairs = []
  not_selected = {0, 1, 2, 3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 1)
  pairs = [0]
  not_selected = {1, 2, 3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 2)
  pairs = [0, 1]
  not_selected = {2, 3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 3)
  pairs = [0, 1, 2]
  not_selected = {3}
  ans = 0

called rec(i = 4)
  pairs = [0, 1, 2, 3]
  not_selected = set()
  ans = 0

4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
        for e in not_selected:
```

`not_selected`の要素についてループしている最中に、`not_selected`を書き換えているのが原因です。
書き換える予定のコンテナは、以下のように、いったんコピーを取ってからループに使用するようにしましょう。

```py
        for e in tuple(not_selected):
```

(修正後の実行結果と比較すると分かりますが、実はPythonでの実行結果も、`pairs = [0, 2]`が2回現れるなど異常な動作をしています)